# Programar Interface apenas uma vez

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform

Gostaria de programar a interface de meu software apenas uma vez e através de alguma ferramenta gerar as telas para Android, IOS e Web Browser. Alguma tecnologia hoje me permitiria isso?

Sei que o Xamarim, por exemplo pode gerar para Android e IOS.

Answer (score 1):

Hoje em dia nossas tecnologias ainda não suprem isso de forma abrangente, porém já há formas consistentes de fazer isso...

**Ciclo de vida dos aplicativos**

As principais libs e frameworks já se adequaram a um sistema de componentização ou um padrão MVC, ou seja, encaixam muito bem no ciclo de vida dos aplicativos.

**Híbridos**

Aplicações híbridas partem de um código em HTML, CSS e Javascript para sistemas diversos. As principais ferramentas utilizadas para o desenvolvimento híbrido são...

- **[Angular](https://angular.io/)**

1 - Aplicativos híbridos

2 - SPA (aplicações de página única)

3 - PWA (Progressive web apps)

Isso atrelados ao [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) para a web view e o [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) para a UI

- **[Vue](https://vuejs.org/)**

1 - Aplicativos híbridos

2 - SPA

3 - PWA

4 - Aplicações desktop

Isso atrelados ao Cordova para a web view e o [Quasar](https://quasar-framework.org/) para a UI

---

Não posso dizer que em um único código você vai conseguir emular para todos os sistemas acima, pois cada tipo de aplicação tem suas particularidades, mas com certeza, boa parte do código poderá ser reaproveitado...

---

**Nativos**

Aplicações nativas são aquelas que se comunicam diretamente com o sistema operacional, ou seja, para Android temos Java, para IOS temo Swift, e sim, com HTML, CSS e JavaScript podemos emular aplicativos nativos, pois a ferramenta que iremos usar, irá compilar o código, elas são...

- **[React](https://reactjs.org/)**

1 - Aplicativos nativos

2 - Aplicações WEB

O React usa o [React Native](http://reactnative.com/) para os aplicativos mobile, e está sendo amplamente usado hoje em dia, infelizmente não tenho conhecimento se todo o aplicativo pode ser compilado para a web, mas existe sim uma lib que mapeia a maioria das APIS e Componentes do React native para a web o [React native web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web), então achei válido colocar...

- **Angular**

1 - Aplicativos nativos

2 - Aplicações WEB

Usando o [Native Script](https://www.nativescript.org/) é possível hoje com o angular desenvolver nativamente, segue um [exemplo](http://shripalsoni.com/blog/create-native-mobile-and-web-app-with-single-codebase-using-angular2-and-nativescript/)

---

Por fim, essa guerra das libs ainda não tem vencedores, cada uma tem suas qualidade e defeitos.

Answer (score 1):

Seria bem legal e prático, né?!

Eu não conheço nenhuma estável em uso, infelizmente, e não acho que - pelo menos a curto e médio prazo - seja uma idéia que vá lhe garantir uma alta produtividade (estou apostando que esse seja o objetivo) sem lhe cobrar um alto preço em manutenibilidade. E isso considerando que a proposta limita-se a atender Web apps, e não sites.

No entanto, recentemente, a Nventive tem um projeto hamado `Uno Platform` (detalhes mais abaixo) que se propõe a fazer isso e *otras cositas mas*. Mas ainda não é uma ferramenta que você vá querer no ambiente de produção, mas promete.

Sem querer confrontar vantagens e desvantagens, o meu intuito é abordar alguns detalhes especificamente sobre essas duas plataformas - mobile e web.

### Quais são os dificultadores dessa ferramenta?

Entre as plataformas `Mobile` e `Desktop` hoje em dia já não há mais tanta diferença de visual e usabilidade, essas duas plataformas se aproximaram muito nos últimos anos. Já entre `esses dois` e a `WEB` há ainda uma sutil (mas poderosa) diferença em alguns aspectos como o **perfil** e **a expectativa do usuário**, os **eventos** disponibilizados, a **navegabilidade**, o **foco** do usuário, a própria **plataforma** e por aí vai.

#### - Perfil do usuário e expectativas do usuário

Nesse contexto de sistemas, usuários e tecnologias, o pessoal da [Geração X](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_X) viu um monte de conceito e tecnologia 'surgir do nada'. Nós da [Geração Y](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Y) já passamos por algumas ondas dessas (r)evolução conceituais e tecnológicas. E os [Gen Z](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Z) nasceram em um cenário que praticamente não conseguem conceber a possibilidade de vida sem o que a tecnologia nos oferece hoje.

Nem todas essas ondas de conceitos e tecnologias morreram, algumas seguem caminhos diferentes e levam consigo suas parcelas de entusiastas e outras surgem em um rítmo crescente.

O fato é que a percepção das tecnologias, seu uso e suas aplicações são bastante diferentes entre essas gerações e isso impacta diretamente nas expectativas que esses atores, no papel de usuários, criam sobre o sistema.

Até alguns anos atrás **sistema** era desktop (ou similar) e **site** era web. Um era para produzir ('informatizar processos', aumentar produtividade, reduzir erros em operações...) e outro era para consumir (navegar, ensinar, aprender, guardar, recuperar, lembrar, descrobrir...).

Hoje tudo é tudo, mas quando estamos usando um aplicativo no celular esperamos mais agilidade - tocou, partiu proximo passo, nada de ficar carregando -, queremos poder dividir a atenção com outros aplicativos - receber uma mensagem no whatsapp ou ouvir a orientação do GPS-.

Não são raras as vezes que por uma pequena percepção de latência em algum recurso de um app, nós o desinstalamos após poquíssimas changes. Não queremos [e geralmente não precisamos] passar por aquela experiência alí. Já em um site somos mais tolerantes com esse tipo de situação.

#### - Eventos e funcionalidades

Entre as plataformas tem eventos, recursos e funcionalidades que nasceram pensado em uma ou outra mas são muito úteis ao que se destina. Há quem levante a bandeira de 'adaptar' a funcionalidade para uma outra plataforma mas não me vem em mente nenhuma experiências agradável nessas tentativas.

Por exemplo, o **movimento de pinça** quando queremos amplicar aquela foto do instagram, perde sentido em um site que, por sua vez, é capaz de responder com alguma coisa **ao passar o mouse sobre ou em direção a determinado elemento**, (já vi umas implementações interessantes nesse sentido, principalmente em site de vendas) ou ainda ao mudar a orientação do dispositivo que está sendo usado.

São coisas com as quais eventualmente iremos querer/precisar lidar e vamos acabar agregando uma complexidade no código que só faz sentido no Cenário X, e penalizando todo o resto por isso.

#### - Foco

Falando novamente de expectativa, geralmente dedicamos maior atenção mas por um intervalo de tempo menor  quando usamos aplicativos. A experiência em uma aplicação web ou site é inversa.

#### - Plataforma

Recursos de navegação entre essas plataformas são bastante plurais. É o caso do GPS, acelerômetro, giroscópio, microfone, câmera e sensores. Alguns desses recursos até estão disponíveis na web, mas são experiências e aplicações comumente diferentes.

Sem falar na arquitetura da solução. De modo geral, o App é um sistema que você 'carrega' cosigo no dispositivo, muitas vezes oferecendo recursos *offline*, já o web app/site é algo que 'está lá' para você consumir. Isso por si só já abre um leque enorme de possibilidades positivas e negativas.

### Desenvolvimento multiplataforma - Uma experiência Xamarin

Como você falou, o Xamarin provê essa possibilidade de desenvolvimento de interface cross-platform, mas o caminho que ele tem percorrido não foi sempre um marde rosas e ainda há espaço para melhorias, mesmo em se tratando de plataformas tão próximas.

Inclusive, ele mesmo ainda oferece a possibilidade (e realmente é uma necessidade) de se construir em código compartilhado, trechos de código que são específicos para uma plataforma. É a partir daí que os problemas de manuteção de código podem começar a surgir.

Hoje o [xamarin.forms](/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms) está enormemente estável e eficiente e continua melhorando, mas mesmo seguindo essa linha, o caminho até o desenvolvimento web ainda é longo.

### O Projeto [*Uno Platform*](http://platform.uno/#)

Voltando ao **Uno**, ele toca justamente no desenvolvimento de interface para múltiplas plataformas usando um com código compartilhado, uma extensão do xamarin, como você pode observar no diagrama da arquitetura da solução:

[image: Arquitetura do Uno Platform]

<sup>Fonte: http://platform.uno/#Architecture</sup>

Seu *slogam* também reforça esse objetivo:

> Build native apps for Mobile and Web using XAML and C#. Uno is a free UWP Bridge for iOS, Android and WebAssembly.

Em tradução livre:

> Crie aplicativos nativos para dispositivos móveis e Web usando XAML e C#. O Uno é uma ponte UWP gratuita para iOS, Android e WebAssembly.

[Nesse vídeo há uma apresentação do Angelo Belchior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z480MrlcCE) sobre os recursos e com algumas demonstrações. Também é possível acessar o [Playgound deles](http://platform.uno/Playground/index.html) e ter sua própria experiência.

Acho que é por algo assim que você procura.

Espero ter ajudado.

> Nota: *Eu acho que esse tipo de pergunta não deveria estar aqui. Mas já que as porteiras estão abertas, deixo aqui minha (des)contibuição =)*.

Answer (score -1):

Creio que uma maneira de fazer isso seria usar um progressive webapp.

De uma olhadinha nesse [tutorial do Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/?hl=pt-br) pra ver se te atende.

Comment: Acho que é pelo contrário, uma PWA pode até substituir um app, pois suas funcionalidades são parecidas com o que os aplicativos nativos oferecem.